# Passing a url parameter along with object in Angularjs POST

Tags: c#, angularjs

I want to update the Order by OrderId. The orderId is int and orderDetails is a JSON object.

AngularJs post function:

```
$http.post("/Order/UpdateOrder/orderId="+orderId, OrderDetails).then(
                            function (obj) {
                                $scope.message = obj.data;
                            },
                            function (ex) {
                                $scope.message = ex;
                            })
```

Controller Function

```
public ActionResult UpdateOrder(String orderId,List<OrderDetailModel> order)
        {
            String result = action.UpdateOrder(order), int.Parse(orderId));
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

On the controller, I am able to get the object. But when I debug The OrderId is always null. I tried changing the parameters sequence. The result is still null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try passing it as QueryString:

```
$http.post("/Order/UpdateOrder?orderId="+orderId, OrderDetails).then(...)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried for 2 days but cannot find that small mistake.